# Доступ к переменной из другого метода. Unity 5.6.6, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Как получить доступ к переменной из другого метода?**

У меня есть метод OnTriggerEnter2D и в нём сразу создаётся Collider2D, который мне и нужен в других методах, но как его взять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете коллайдер полем в классе, инициализируете его в методе соприкосновения, в других методах делаете проверку, что коллайдер инициализирован:

```
public class ColliderCreationInOnTriggerEnter2D : MonoBehaviour {

    private Collider2D extraCollider = null;

    private void Update() {
        if(extraCollider != null) {
            Debug.Log("I have a new collider!");
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("collider field wasn't initalized :(");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        extraCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<Collider2D>();

        // настраиваете свой коллайдер здесь
        // например, делаем его триггером
        extraCollider.isTrigger = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто сделать коллайдер в поле класса недостаточно. Ведь я сказал в вопросе, что при создании метода OnTriggerEnter2D надо в скобках СОЗДАТЬ новый коллайдер, поэтому в класс коллайдер не поместить, ибо коллайдер создаётся в самом методе. Или я не правильно понял ваше решение?

Comment: *> надо в скобках СОЗДАТЬ новый коллайдер*  

Вы о чем? Либо объясните подробнее, либо приложите фрагмент кода. Либо и то, и другое сразу.

Comment: @RinktonGames эм, если вы добавите в класс поле `Collider2D collider`, то никакой коллайдер не создастся, это лишь переменная-ссылка, которая при таком объявлении будет равно `null`. В методе `OnTriggerEnter2D` никто не мешает написать (условно) `collider = new Collider2D(...)`, и эта переменная будет указывать на новый объект типа `Collider2D`.

Comment: `=! `? Новый оператор?

Comment: @ヒミコ опечатка, спасибо, что заметили

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Можете пожалуйста привести пример кода с использованием информации вашего комментария выше, я вас не понимаю

Comment: насколько я понял то вы хотите добавить еще коллайдер. Можете использовать AddComponent<ConcreteCollider>();

и просто присвоить его полю класса и использовать та где нужно.

Comment: @RinktonGames каким образом вы "создаете" коллайдер в методе соприкосновения?

Comment: @RinktonGames дополнил ответ

Comment: Вообщем, в итоге я нашёл решение проблемы совершенно другим способом. Поэтому вопрос можно считать закрытым. Во всяком случае, ваш ответ ответил на изначальный вопрос, поэтому он верный. Спасибо 
всем за то, что помогали мне с моей проблемой